# display next prior Last record on dataset in winform

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0

i want to display record of the Dataset in text box on button click `Next` , `Prior` and `Last` record on winform . So how can i do this . I am not using `bindingNavigator` on the form . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the problem? Store the current row-index in a field and then advance/go back accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the current row-index in  a field, the rest is straight-forward (`ds` is your `DataSet`):

```
private int RowIndex { get; set; }

private void Navigate(int recordIndex)
{
    if (recordIndex < 0 || recordIndex >= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException("The record-index must be between 0 and row-count-1", "recordIndex");
    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[recordIndex];
    string field = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
    yourTextBox.Text = field;
}
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{ 
    int rowIndex = RowIndex + 1;
    if(rowIndex >= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
        rowIndex = 0;
    Navigate(rowIndex);
}
private void btnPrior_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    int rowIndex = RowIndex - 1;
    if (rowIndex < 0)
        rowIndex = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; // go to last
    Navigate(rowIndex);
}
private void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigate(0);
}
private void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Navigate(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1);
}
```